# database convertor

Tags: mysql, postgresql, db-structure

I have table with many data and also I have new structure in other database and system. Is there any program to convert database to new structure?

This program must read structure of both of them and then ask me which field fill which field in new table and also which field drop and etc ...

can any body suggest any application do these things for me?

Also my sql file is MySQL and my structure (new table) is PostgreSQL

Comment: SQL Server has SSIS which will do this and doesn't (IIRC) need to involve SQL Server. However I don't think SSIS is available for the express version - you'd need a full SQL Server install.

Comment: I suspect you can find something, but depending on the amount of data, I think it might be easier to write it yourself. That way you don't get stuck on the limitations of the tool. If you have lots of data, or limited experience, then maybe this is a bad idea.

Comment: @MJB at last i find your answer is best answer :((

Comment: Sorry to hear that. But I guess that's why we get paid the big bucks, right?

Answer (score 1):

There are [several mysql => postgres scripts](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL) listed in the postgres wiki, and there's [a good guide on syntax changes here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL#Changing_The_Code_Quick_And_Dirty)

Comment: there is no problem with read from mysql and write to postgresql, but i want application do this staf

Comment: There are several such applications listed in the first link I provided.